# Ubuntu18 and ROS melodic catkin error: ImportError: No module named terminal_color

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I exactly followed the instructions from http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu.

Then I created a workspace by

```
cd
mkdior -p catkin_ws/src
cd catkin_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
cd ..
catkin_make
```

The I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/bin/catkin_make", line 13, in <module>
    from catkin.terminal_color import disable_ANSI_colors, fmt
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin/terminal_color.py", line 2, in <module>
    from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import *  # noqa
ImportError: No module named terminal_color
```

I googled and tried everything I could(except for reinstalling my OS). But the problem is still there.

For example, to give more info:

Run

```
sudo dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg
```

and got

```
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/catkin_generate_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_prepare_release
/usr/bin/catkin_tag_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_create_pkg
/usr/bin/catkin_test_changelog
/usr/bin/catkin_package_version
/usr/bin/catkin_find_pkg
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info/entry_points.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg-0.4.3.egg-info/PKG-INFO
```

And

```
python -c 'import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__file__)'
```

got

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.pyc
```

And

```
printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules
/usr/share/doc/python-catkin-pkg-modules/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/metapackage.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_membership.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/tool_detection.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cmake.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_templates.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/package_version.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/group_dependency.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/workspaces.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/CMakeLists.txt.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/metapackage.cmake.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/templates/package.xml.in
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/changelog_generator_vcs.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/rospack.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/condition.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/generate_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/find_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/create_pkg.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/test_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/cli/tag_changelog.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.1.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.1.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.1.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.1.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.1.egg-info/PKG-INFO
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294780/ubuntu18-and-ros-melodic-catkin-error:-importerror:-no-module-named-terminal_color/) by [Jaxxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/35983/jaxxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2018-06-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Python module in question has recently been moved from `catkin` into `catkin_pkg`. It is actually in the Debian `python-catkin-pkg-modules`. Can you please post the output of `dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules`. Maybe you haven't update that package to the same version as `python-catkin-pkg`?

*Edit:*
Make sure both packages are up-to-date: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg python-catkin-pkg-modules`

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaxxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/35983/jaxxl/) on 2018-06-21**:
Thanks for your answer! The version indeed does not match. I fixed the problem by upgrading `python-catkin-pkg-modules` with `sudo pip install --upgrade catkin_pkg_modules`.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-08**:
We highly discourage users to install these packages through `pip`. The problem is that even if you install future versions of the Debian package the pip installed version will be used and likely leading to problem.

**Comment by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on 2018-08-27**:
"sudo apt update && sudo apt install python-catkin-pkg python-catkin-pkg-modules" says that everything is up to date with ROS kinetic but the problem persists.

**Comment by [inspire](https://answers.ros.org/users/28884/inspire/) on 2018-08-27**:
okay I found a workaround: https://answers.ros.org/question/301702/ros-kinetic-importerror-no-module-named-terminal_color/?answer=301712#post-id-301712

**Comment by [cwbullivant](https://answers.ros.org/users/40652/cwbullivant/) on 2019-04-04**:
I am having the same problem as this user was, but when I try to run the command you recommend, I get a result saying:

sudo: python-catkin-pkg: command not found

Have any other names been changed since last June?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-04**:
The right command is: `sudo apt install --reinstall python-catkin-pkg python-catkin-pkg-modules`

**Comment by [cwbullivant](https://answers.ros.org/users/40652/cwbullivant/) on 2019-04-11**:
I've run that command and the packages were reinstalled. However, the error persists.

I ran dpkg -L python-catkin-pkg-modules after reinstalling and got mostly the same output as the above user (with these added lines at the bottom):

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.11.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.11.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.11.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.11.egg-info/requires.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg_modules-0.4.11.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

Even more strangely, typing "from catkin_pkg.terminal_color import *" into the interpreter from the command line works just fine. It's only when this line is invoked from catkin_make that it fails.

**Comment by [liqsuq](https://answers.ros.org/users/44074/liqsuq/) on 2019-07-16**:
I have run above command, but python-catkin-pkg-modules was not found.
And python-catkin-pkg had no dependencies.
However, the error is occurring.  Any ideas?

```
$ uname -v
#26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 27 07:28:31 UTC 2019
$ sudo apt install python-catkin-pkg-modules
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-catkin-pkg-modules
$ apt list | grep python-catkin-pkg

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

python-catkin-pkg/bionic,bionic,now 0.3.9-1 all [installed]
```